# How do I deaden the sound of water dripping on metal?

Tags: hvac, insulation, air-conditioning, waterproofing

I live in a two story apartment complex (upstairs neighbors are REAL nice). My bedroom has an AC Box/Swamp Cooler mounted into the wall. Directly above it is a similar unit for my neighbors.

The problem is that when it gets unbearably hot (as it does during summers here) the upper unit eventually starts to drip water directly down onto the top of my unit. This creates an immensely frustrating sound in my room, as the hollow metal box in my wall echoes this consistent dripping noise, keeping me from falling asleep or enjoying the quiet in general.

I have asked the landlords if they can either repair the upstairs unit or put a barrier between the water and my unit, but their response was "Meh, swamp coolers drip, get over it."

I feel like i'm going to have to fix this problem myself and am wondering what I can do to stop the dripping.

Comment: Go buy some PVC tubing, and attach it to the upper unit's weep hole, then direct it to the left or to the right.

Comment: tie a string in a location where the drops originate ... the water will then run quietly down the string

Answer (score 3):

If the drip is that noisy, it's probably hitting a flat horizontal spot on your unit. If you can add something to the top of your unit that is at a steep angle that the drip lands on, the drip shouldn't be as noticable.

You might be able to put a flower pot with just sand in it, or even an actual plant with soil on it on top of your unit?

Comment: I thought of a sponge, that could help as well. But the water is still there, shouldn't it be drained?

Comment: Wouldn't the water eventually make the pot heavy enough to potentially destabilize the unit's rigging to the point of dangerously causing it to fall down? Also, Do you have any specific suggestion for such a sloped object?

Answer (score 2):

The answer may depend slightly on whether the cooler is refrigeration air conditioning (the dripping water is condensate) or swamp cooler (the dripping water is a leak of fresh running water) because the volume of water could be substantially different between the two.

If the water droplets fall onto something with more mass, such as thick metal plate or a brick, there'll be less noise made. Slope it as suggested by [Dotes](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/167232/45928) for even better results.

An alternative is to catch the drip before it happens. One way to do this is inspired by the concept of a rain chain. The idea is to provide a path for rivulets of water to run down rather than falling freely as droplets. Attach a length of chain, rope, wire, etc so that the droplets forming on the upper unit get pulled onto the surface of the rain chain. They'll run silently down to the end of the chain. If drips form at multiple places they could be gathered with some kind of pan (a baking sheet pan for example), or multiple rain chains could be employed -- joined into a single chain if desired, or each left to hang separately.

Comment: Do you have any specific suggestion for such a sloped object?

Comment: @OhadSchneider It's going to require some site-specific creativity. This is the sort of thing for which one might use materials that are already on hand: a brick, a rock, a piece of metal, a chunk of wood, etc. The things may have to be stacked, cut, glued, taped, nailed, screwed, or otherwise attached so that a slope is created and the object remains stable in its intended place.